# Unable to load the jar files which are on the classpath

Tags: java, ant, jar, cmd, executable-jar

I am trying to run my jar file by executing 
  `java -jar myJarFile.jar arg1`  
but it throws `ClassNotFoundException !` for the classfiles which are referred in my class files. FYI, these class files are present in some external jars which i have placed on my classpath by setting the env `CLASSPATH` variable pointing to the directory where all the external jars are placed. And my MANIFEST.MF would look like 
  
`Manifest-Version: 1.0 

Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1 

Created-By: 20.14-b01 (Sun Microsystems Inc.) 

Main-Class: com.abc.test.FileGenerator 

BuildDate: 01/10/2014 12:52:36 

Class-Path: C:\libraries\commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar C:\libraries\commons-collections.jar 

 C:\libraries\commons-discovery-0.2.jar C:\libraries\commons-lang-2.5.jar 

 C:\libraries\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar C:\libraries\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar`

My main class is available in my jar and I am running from where my jar is getting created by ant script like dist folder. I even changed the absolute path to relative path.. It is still throwing the same error. Here is my jar structure -  

`myFile.jar

    |- com 

    |   |

    |   abc

    |   |

    |   test

    |   |-package1

    |   |-package2

    |   |-FileGenerator.class

    |

    |-META-INF 
|                                                        |- MANIFEST.MF` 



Kindly help me on this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue is with the path of the external jar set in the classpath,cross check it.

Comment: well, I have placed them in a directory named libraries and I have set the classpath as   CLASSPATH=C:\libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the paths to all your jar files in the CLASSPATH, putting only a directory will cause jvm to look for `.class` files of which the packages start from that directory not `.jar` files.

So set your classpath something like this (windows):

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\path\to\libs\somelib1.jar;path2\to\libs\somelib2.jar
```

and so on.

You have then to run your program like this:

```
java your.main.Klass arg1
```

Alternatively you could add a `Calss-path` entry in your manifest and put all your dependencies in it:

```
Class-Path: libs/somelib1.jar libs/somelib3.jar
```

Then you can run it using the `-jar` option

```
java -jar myJarFile.jar arg1
```

Comment: I tried! but now i am getting ClassNotFoundException for my main class itself!! :( . My MANIFEST.MF looks like <br /> <code> Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 20.14-b01 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: com.abc.test.FileGenerator
BuildDate: 01/10/2014 12:52:36
Class-Path: C:\libraries\commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar C:\libraries\commons-collections.jar 
 C:\libraries\commons-discovery-0.2.jar C:\libraries\commons-lang-2.5.jar 
 C:\libraries\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar C:\libraries\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar  <br/> </code>

Comment: @netuser Please check that you have no typos in the name of your main class. Also please make sure that the main class is available in the jar file you create. Finally, please avoid do no using absolute paths for your dependencies, place the folder `libraries` near your jar and use the relative path in your manifest: `Class-Path: libraries\commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar libraries\commons-collections.jar ...`. Run the command from the directory where your jar is located.

Comment: Yes, main class is available in my jar and I am running from where my jar is getting created by ant script like dist folder. I even changed the absolute path to relative path.. It is still throwing the same error. Here is my jar structuer - <code>
myFile.jar
 |- com
 | |
 | abc
 | |
 | test
 | |-package1
 | |-package2
 | |-MainClass.class
 |
 |- META-INF
  |-MANIFEST.MF   <code>

Comment: @netuser please edit your question and post those informations in it properly formated, also post your directory tree and point from where you start the program.

Answer (score 1):

Using -jar tells the JVM to ignore any other classpath settings (include CLASSPATH and -cp).  You have to give a classpath in your manifest file at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the classpaths of your external jar in your manifest file like

```
Class-Path: abc.jar def.jar folder/ghi.jar
```

and then run your command `java -jar myJarFile.jar arg1`

Comment: I tried! but now i am getting ClassNotFoundException for my main class itself!! :( . My MANIFEST.MF looks like <br /> <code> Manifest-Version: 1.0 Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1 Created-By: 20.14-b01 (Sun Microsystems Inc.) Main-Class: com.abc.test.FileGenerator BuildDate: 01/10/2014 12:52:36 Class-Path: C:\libraries\commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar C:\libraries\commons-collections.jar C:\libraries\commons-discovery-0.2.jar C:\libraries\commons-lang-2.5.jar C:\libraries\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar C:\libraries\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar <br/> </code>

Comment: @net user, My friend have you run this command from the folder where your main class is or from the parent directory of your package folder and please give the relative paths in your Class-Path: tag in manifest file

Comment: @net user if my solution works for you please right click on my answer, so it will be helpful for others my friend

Comment: I am running from a directory where my jar is placed, like C:\dis> java -jar myfile.jar arg1 and in the manifest file i have given the absolute path like c:\libraries\jar1.jar c:\libraries\jar2.jar . But still it is not working.. :(

Comment: My friend please try with relative path like ../libraries/jar2.jar in your classpath in manifest file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44980/discussion-between-net-user-and-girishlalwani2010)